# Variations of actions of (lie algebra valued) differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, action, chern-simons-theory

I have always found it a bit difficult to understand the variation of an action written in differential form language. For example, take the action

$$\int tr A\wedge A\wedge A$$

where $A=A_\mu dx^\mu=A^I_\mu T_I dx^\mu$ is a one form valued in some Lie algebra (this is basically one part of a chern simons action). Now the variation is supposed to give the equations of motion $A\wedge A=0$, however, this is far from trivial to me. If I write it out I get

$$\int A^I_\mu A^J_\nu A^K_\rho tr(T_I T_J T_K) dx^\mu\wedge dx^\nu \wedge dx^\rho$$

Now I suppose I want to vary with respect to the $A_\mu^I$ to get something like

$$\int 3(dA^I_\mu) A^J_\nu A^K_\rho tr(T_I T_J T_K) dx^\mu\wedge dx^\nu \wedge dx^\rho$$

It is still far from trivial to me what this means. We can try to write it as a normal integral by using $dx^\mu\wedge dx^\nu \wedge dx^\rho\sim \epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho} dx^3$ to obtain the following equations of motion

$$\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho}A^J_\nu A^K_\rho tr(T_I T_J T_K)=0\Rightarrow A_\nu^J A_\mu^K tr (T_I T_L c_{JK}^L)=0$$

where the $c$ are the structure constants. Now the trace should define a non-degenerate bilinear form $tr(T_IT_J)=g_{IJ}$, and from this one can indeed find that $A_\nu^J A_\mu^K c_{JK}^L=0$ which indeed is equivalent to $A\wedge A=0$. (I think this calculation is correct but corrections are welcome)

However I find this derivation very cumbersome and complicated to derive such an "obvious" result. So how should I think of variations of actions written with differential forms? what are the rules for doing such variations?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I never had to actually encounter Lie-algebra valued difforms before, but I assume the following could work:

When we are talking about a variation of $A$, what we mean is that we take a smooth, one-parameter family of $A$s, let's call them $A_\varepsilon$, such that $A_0=A$. Then $\delta=d/d\varepsilon|_{\varepsilon=0}$.

Now then $$ \delta\int\mathrm{tr}(A\wedge A\wedge A)=\int\delta\mathrm{tr}(A\wedge A\wedge A)=\\ =\int\mathrm{tr}(\delta A\wedge A\wedge A+A\wedge\delta A\wedge A+A\wedge A\wedge\delta A)=\\ =\int\mathrm{tr}(A\wedge A\wedge\delta A)=0, $$ we reduced from three terms to one because rearranging the wedges, two of the terms are equivalent, and one is the negative of the others. Since this must be true for **arbitrary** $\delta A$ variations, this implies that $A\wedge A=0$.